# templated class containing vector of class objects defined by typedef. How to call them in main?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a templated class that contains type of vectors of that class defined by typedef, how do I call or initialize them in the main file?

in Non template class I can initialize these typdef vectors by just calling:
Node::nodes1d newnodes1d(5); But I am lost how to do this when templated classes are involved?

```
template{class T}class Node{
  Node(){};
  T a;
T b;
    typedef vector<T> nodes1d;
};
```

Comment: Does this code compile?

Comment: And generally it's Node<type>::nodes1d for the any type.

Answer (score 0):

Without more context, it's hard to say exactly what you need, but generally you would call it in main like this:

```
Node::nodes1d myNodesList;
```

Of course, `nodes1d` would have to be in the `public` section of the class definition.

Comment: I forgot to add the public:

Comment: The main problem I am facing is that  the vector I want to create will be of type "Node".  Without the templated class your suggested method is what I am using now. But when i introduced templated class I dont know how to call it any more. anyways thanks. :)

Comment: Perhaps you mean `std::vector<Node<type>>`? And if you want to say thanks, you can always accept this answer if it properly answers your question :)